# jQuery AJAX call disables input box

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

so I have a web page that does an Ajax call to get data from the server. However when I trigger the Ajax call, an input box (#serial in this case) on my web page stops being responsive (I can't type on it or anything). Does anyone know what causes this?

```
<div id="filterconfig">
    <b>Serial Number:</b> <br/><input type="text" id="serial"/> <br/>
<button type="button" onclick="clicked($('#serial').val(), $('[name=location]:checked').val(), $('#exception'), $('[name=direction]:checked').val(),$('[name=server]:checked').val())">Filter</button>
</div>
```

Here's the function being called:

```
$(document).ready(assignOnclick);

    function assignOnclick() {
        $("tbody > tr").click(function () {
            $(this).onclick = GetSelectedReadableForm(this);
        });
    }

function callAjax() {
        var urlHuman = encodeURI(someUrl);
        var urlHex = encodeURI(someUrl);

        $.ajax({
            url: urlHuman,
            async:false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#stringview').find('.human').val(data);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: urlHex,
            async:false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#stringview').find('.hex').val(data);
            }
        });

    }

    function GetSelectedReadableForm(obj) {
        $("tr").css({ 'background-color': '' });
        $(obj).closest('tr').css({ 'background-color': '#ccc' });
        row_id = parseInt($(obj).closest('tr').find('#rowID').attr("value"));
        callAjax();
    }
```

Comment: It's the `async : false`, it's the root of all evil, and it will lock the browser.

Comment: @adeneo it's still happening without the `async: false` :(

Comment: Then you're doing something else that messes it up

Answer (score 1):

in jquery doc:

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   **Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser**,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active.

do you really need sync request ?!

you can try to synchronize result with ansyncronous requests:

```
    $.when(
      $.ajax({ url: urlHuman, cache: false}),
      $.ajax({ url: urlHex, cache: false})
    ).done( function(data1, data2) {
      $('#stringview').find('.human').val(data1);
      $('#stringview').find('.hex').val(data2);
    });
```

Comment: I wanted a sync request because it made the loading of the `#stringviews` happen at the same time, but that does not seem to be the issue. It is literally just that one input box, my other buttons (radio buttons etc and other things work)

Comment: you can use $.when to synchronize request results

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was assigning a whole function to the "onkeydown" event, and it was preventing default behavior on keypresses that weren't intended for it